# Deleting a row if duplicated then filtered on another column

Tags: excel, vba

I am filtering a table with loads of horserace information. I have done 7 of 8 filters but I am struggling with the last one. Basically *all* I need is to look at the column with the time of the race (col B), if there are 2 times the same then obviously there are 2 selections in the race. I only want one selection so next I want to delete/filter row based on column C which is Trainer win %. Whichever is the bigger % that is the one I need to keep. If they are the same maybe put msgbox to say so or I may have to filter with a 3rd field. I have found a piece of code that is getting close.

```
Sub text()      
Dim j As Integer, k As Integer, r As Range      
j = Range("E2").End(xlDown).Row      
For k = j To 2 Step -1      
    MsgBox k      
    Set r = Range(Cells(k, "E"), Cells(k, "E").End(xlUp))      
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r, Cells(k, "E")) > 1 Then      
        Cells(k, "E").EntireRow. Delete      
    End If      
Next k      
End Sub
```

Comment: please format your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the data on the trainer win percentage (descending) and then use the [Range.RemoveDuplicates method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx) on the times.

```
Sub tract()
    With Worksheets("Sheet6")    '<~~ you should know which worksheet you are on
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            'sort on the trainer win percentage (descending)
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(3), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            'remove duplicate times - the lower rows will be deleted
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Remove Duplicates always removes the lower entry; keeping the entry closer to the top. This is why sorting on the trainer win percentages first is important. This does not account for cases where the win percentages are also duplicate. In that case, another sort key would have to be added. If column Z was the deciding factor and you wanted to keep the lower values then it would be similar to the following.

```
Sub tract()
    With Worksheets("Sheet6")    '<~~ you should know which worksheet you are on
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            'sort on the trainer win percentage (descending) and columns Z (ascending)
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(3), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                        Key2:=.Columns(26), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            'remove duplicate times - the lower rows will be deleted
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Jeeped that's worked perfectly. Wished I'd asked a week ago. Cheers

Comment: Hi. I have just found that when I run the above code after filtering, it does not always give the correct result. It looks at the "hidden" filtered items and deletes the lower trainer percentage. Is there a way of only executing code on records that are visible and not comparing with the hidden filtered records?

Comment: The [Range.RemoveDuplicates method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx) is not restricted to visible cells but there are other methods that could only process a filtered set. Suggest you close off this question and start another lest this become a [Russian Doll Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions).

Comment: I will close the question off, as soon as I figure out how. Thanks again